# Error: Attempt to reference field of non-structure array. (using global vars)

Tags: matlab, global-variables

I'm trying to modify someone else's code that uses global variables and keep getting an error that I can't figure out. This is my first time using global variables, so I suspect it has to do with that.  I'm getting this error:

```
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Error in likelihood (line 35)
X=ModelInfo.X;
```

This is the code I run:

```
clearvars -global
clearvars
global ModelInfo

%Pull in data from MySQL database
ModelInfo.X=.....   %76x2 double type
ModelInfo.y=.....   %76x1 double type

addpath('C:/.../Sampling Plans');
addpath('C:/.../Constructing a Surrogate');

%Number of variables
k=size(ModelInfo.X,2);
%Number of sample points
n=size(ModelInfo.X,1);
%Set upper and lower bounds for search of log theta
UpperTheta=ones(1,k).*2;
LowerTheta=ones(1,k).*-3;

%Run GA search of likelihood
[ModelInfo.Theta,MinNegLnLikelihood]=ga(@likelihood,k,[],[],[],[],LowerTheta,UpperTheta);
```

...which references an outside function likelihood (written by someone else):

```
function [NegLnLike,Psi,U]=likelihood(x)

global ModelInfo
X=ModelInfo.X;
y=ModelInfo.y;
theta=10.^x;
p=2; 
n=size(X,1);
one=ones(n,1);

% Pre-allocate memory
Psi=zeros(n,n);
% Build upper half of correlation matrix
for i=1:n
    for j=i+1:n
        Psi(i,j)=exp(-sum(theta.*abs(X(i,:)-X(j,:)).^p)); 
    end
end

% Add upper and lower halves and diagonal of ones plus 
% small number to reduce ill-conditioning
Psi=Psi+Psi'+eye(n)+eye(n).*eps; 

% Cholesky factorisation
[U,p]=chol(Psi);

% Use penalty if ill-conditioned
if p>0
    NegLnLike=1e4;
else

    % Sum lns of diagonal to find ln(abs(det(Psi)))
    LnDetPsi=2*sum(log(abs(diag(U))));

    % Use back-substitution of Cholesky instead of inverse
    mu=(one'*(U\(U'\y)))/(one'*(U\(U'\one)));
    SigmaSqr=((y-one*mu)'*(U\(U'\(y-one*mu))))/n;
    NegLnLike=-1*(-(n/2)*log(SigmaSqr) - 0.5*LnDetPsi);
end
```

**UPDATE:**

Figured out the problem.  I declared ModelInfo as a global variable at the beginning, and then within the `%Pull in data from MySQL database` section I created a database connection and then cleared some variables we wouldn't need anymore using the `clearvars -except` command, but I didn't include ModelInfo in that list.  After that I put data into ModelInfo.  Since it's global, I guess that deleted either the local copy or the global copy (not quite sure), but it still appeared in the list of variables in the workspace and `isstruct(ModelInfo)` still returned 1...so visibly there was nothing to indicate an issue other than the error.

Answer (score 1):

If that is indeed the code you run:

```
%Pull in data from MySQL database
ModelInfo.X=.....   %76x2 double type
ModelInfo.y=.....   %76x1 double type
```

I doubt it has anything to do with global variables. You should have some data of some sort instead of the 5 dots `.....` in order to make any code work (as the comment that is placed above indicate "pull data from..."). I'd also try to make this data in the form that the comments suggest if it isn't of the same class, i.e. make it `double` and of the size mentioned.

For example, try to see if replacing these lines with this makes your code work

```
ModelInfo.X=rand(76,2)   %76x2 double type
ModelInfo.y=rand(76,1)   %76x1 double type
```

Comment: Sorry, there is code in those places...it's just rather lengthy because it involves some MySQL queries and is not involved in the error, so I left it out.  Those lines execute correctly and result in double type matrices of the dimensions mentioned.  The error occurs on the last line, while trying to execute the ga() function.

Comment: I actually copied your code and used the random matrices input, and it works in my machine... (Matlab 2012a)

Comment: @Amy I can confirm that if you perform the replacement suggested by @natan, then the code runs fine (R2012b). This suggests the problem lies in the `%Pull in data from MySQL database` section and has nothing to do with global variables. Try running your code again, and once the error is thrown, type `isstruct(ModelInfo)` at the command line. If it returns a `0`, then `ModelInfo` is definitely not a structure...

Comment: Very strange.  I tried the code with random numbers substituted in for ModelInfo.X and ModelInfo.y, and sure enough that works.  When I use my code to pull the data from an external database, it errors.  isstruct(ModelInfo) returns a value of 1...

Comment: If I use my database connection code to build ModelInfo.X and ModelInfo.y first, and then overwrite them with random numbers using natan's suggestion, it still errors.  Checking isstruct(ModelInfo) after each change always returns a value of 1.